# iOS 10: CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage

In my iPhone app, I've always used the following function to `horizontally mirror` an image.

```
-(UIImage*)mirrorImage:(UIImage*)img
{
    CIImage *coreImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage];
    coreImage = [coreImage imageByApplyingTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];
    img = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:coreImage scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    return img;
}
```

With iOS 10.0.1 though, this function still runs with no errors, but when I try to use the `UIImage` from this function, the following warning appears, and the image just doesn't seem to be there.

```
Failed to render 921600 pixels because a CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling.
```

This error actually appears in the Output window when I attempt to *use* the `UIImage` (in the second line in this code) :

```
UIImage* flippedImage = [self mirrorImage:originalImage];    
UIImageView* photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:flippedImage];
```

After calling `mirrorImage`, the `flippedImage` variable *does* contain a value, it's not `nil`, but when I try to use the image, I get that error message.

If I were to *not call* the `mirrorImage` function, then the code works fine:

```
UIImageView* photo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
```

Is there some new quirk with `iOS 10` which would prevent my `mirrorImage` function from working ?

Just to add, in the `mirrorImage` function, I tried testing the size of the image before and after the transformation (as the error is complaining about having to `tile` the image), and the size is identical.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by converting CIImage -> CGImage -> UIImage

```
let ciImage: CIImage = "myCIImageFile"

let cgImage: CGImage = {
    let context = CIContext(options: nil)
    return context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)!
}()

let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

I don't know what `iOS 10` has broken, but I managed to fix the problem by replacing my function with this:

```
-(UIImage*)mirrorImage:(UIImage*)img
{
    UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage
                                                scale:img.scale
                                          orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    return flippedImage;
}
```