# Swift error in console "CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling"

Tags: swift, transform, translate, ciimage, cikernel

Full error is "Failed to render 921600 pixels because a CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling." every time I try to transform a ciImage with a translation.

Code is simply:

```
    var flippedGradient = gradient.transformed(by:CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1))
    flippedGradient = gradient.transformed(by:CGAffineTransform(translationX: flippedGradient.extent.width, y: 0)) // causes error

    // mask hue 2 with gradient with transparent background
    let alphaMaskBlend2 = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithAlphaMask",
                                   withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: hue2,
                                                         kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: transBGCI,
                                                         kCIInputMaskImageKey:flippedGradient])?.outputImage
```

Doing a translation causes the error and makes me entire screen gray instead of rendering the image otherwise normally.

Related thread, with no resolutions related to how I would be able to translate my ciImage:
[iOS 10: CIKernel's ROI function did not allow tiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40739037/ios-10-cikernels-roi-function-did-not-allow-tiling)

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me for the lateness, but I just ran across the same error and *may* have some help. I was using a different filter (`CIShadedMaterial`) and worked around it by trimming my image down to a smaller size. Here's my code:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resizeToBoundingSquare(_ boundingSquareSideLength : CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let imgScale = self.size.width > self.size.height ? boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.width : boundingSquareSideLength / self.size.height
        let newWidth = self.size.width * imgScale
        let newHeight = self.size.height * imgScale
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return resizedImage!
    }
```

Usage:

```
myImage = myImage.resizeToBoundingSquare(640)
```

- I was using 4096 originally and realized I left that in.
- Credit really needs to go to [Simon Gladman](http://flexmonkey.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/two-handy-swift-extensions-hermite.html) for this. I couldn't find the *exact* place where I found that using 640x640 is "good enough" but this link is "close enough".